# Slowly download files via PHP from Direct Admin

Tags: php, download, directadmin

I try using `file_get_contents()`, `cURL`, `FTP`... to download files from *Direct Admin* server. It runs slowly and takes about 2 minutes to download `10MB`.

When I download files from *VestaCP* server. It takes about 2-5 seconds to download `10MB`.

How can I solve this problem. I have root account of this *Direct Admin* server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's totally depend on your server provider and network speed which they have assigned to your server. If your both server are hosted in same network then might be there is an issues with your server firewall. Please try to disable firewall of your directadmin server and check again.